# Android webview app shows "complete the action using" popups

Tags: android, web, webview

I am working with android app for the web view. It loads the webpage but i cant make more actions on the page using my app. when I am choosing a hyperlink from the page it shows a popup"complete the action using chrome,opera etc.." how can I use this without such browsers..I nedd to browse web contents using my app. how it possible??

I used the code

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

please help me since I am new to android and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wv.loadUrl(url);
wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Your WebViewCLient class would look like this:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override

    // show the web page in webview but not in web browser
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        webProg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what is "webProg" here ??

Comment: Sorry about that. It is an object of a progress bar. It displays itself until the page has completely loaded.